# Not supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh

I use Git to generate a key pair. The private key has this format with no extension (probably the .pem format):

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I want to login to my server (ubuntu@18.138.255.242) with my private key. WinSCP requires me to convert that key to .ppk format. It now looks like this:

```
PuTTY-User-Key-File-2: ssh-rsa
Encryption: none
Comment: Ooker@PC
Public-Lines: 9
...
Private-Lines: 21
...
Private-MAC: ...
```

However after everything is done it shows this error: `Not supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`. I've googled it but it doesn't yield useful answer. However I can still login to my own EC2 instance without problem.

Do you know what's wrong?

[image]

Comment: What did you do to make the server recognize the key after you have generated it?

Comment: It's my technician does it for me. Because we are a volunteering and he's busy, but still responsive to other more important tasks, I assume that everything is setup correctly on his side

Comment: Well, it does not look like it is.

Comment: if the pubkey I sent him is correct, then what can go wrong? I know this is speculative and it's best to just ask him to look at it, I still want to have some insights, so that my request is intriguing to him

Comment: Can you log in with git's ssh, i.e. might it be a problem converting the key? Is it definitely ubuntu@ and not e.g. ec2-user@ if he's switched to Amazon Linux?